# How do I filter experts-exchange.com permanently from my online search results?

Tags: search, resultset

Experts-Exchange is at it again; relevant help blocked behind membership fees. I don't want to support that, so I want to remove their site from my search results. How does one go about that. I am mainly using Google.

I have tried "-site" but I don't want to manually add that everytime. Is there a solution where I can filter sites from my search results?